# Whe webViewDidStartLoad was hit several times when loading one website?

Tags: iphone

I just found that when the WebView is loading www.abc.com, and webViewDidStartLoad were hit for several times. Why not only one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on the webpage.

For instance, if the webpage has ads that come from Google Ads then it has to load your webpage and load the ads, or if it has Facebook Login it has to do another request to bring back that image.

In the case of abc.com I'd say you're hitting it several times because it is redirecting you to http://abc.go.com/.